# Rosetta url get the url based on the build id

Tags: xml, bash, xpath, xmllint

i have XML file and i am trying to get the URL ends with RosettaUpdateAuto.pkg compared with BuildVersion if equals and fetch the url for the RosettaUpdateAuto.pkg.

BuildVersion 20A5374g is equals and get the URL : https://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/04/39/001-50263-A_LEF5A7Q02Z/s4d18996ppu4gczumkptqmljgay795qmvl/RosettaUpdateAuto.pkg

```
    <dict>
        <key>CatalogVersion</key>
        <integer>2</integer>
        <key>ApplePostURL</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>IndexDate</key>
        <date>2023-01-13T00:35:44Z</date>
        <key>Products</key>
        <dict>
            <key>001-50263</key>
            <dict>
                <key>ServerMetadataURL</key>
                <string>https://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/04/39/001-50263-A_LEF5A7Q02Z/s4d18996ppu4gczumkptqmljgay795qmvl/RosettaUpdateAuto.smd</string>
                <key>Packages</key>
                <array>
                    <dict>
                        <key>Digest</key>
                        <string>f3a58e780d28ecbdbad32c66049abdb235352245</string>
                        <key>Size</key>
                        <integer>392574</integer>
                        <key>MetadataURL</key>
                        <string>https://swdist.apple.com/content/downloads/04/39/001-50263-A_LEF5A7Q02Z/s4d18996ppu4gczumkptqmljgay795qmvl/RosettaUpdateAuto.pkm</string>
                        <key>URL</key>
                        <string>https://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/04/39/001-50263-A_LEF5A7Q02Z/s4d18996ppu4gczumkptqmljgay795qmvl/RosettaUpdateAuto.pkg</string>
                    </dict>
                </array>
                <key>ExtendedMetaInfo</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>ProductType</key>
                    <string>otherArchitectureHandlerOS</string>
                    <key>BuildVersion</key>
                    <string>20A5374g</string>
                </dict>
                <key>PostDate</key>
                <date>2020-09-18T01:24:13Z</date>
                <key>Distributions</key>
            </dict>
 </dict>
 </dict>
```

Comment: Whyhaveyouleftoutallthespacesinyourtitle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
url=$(xmllint --xpath '//key[text()="ExtendedMetaInfo"]/following-sibling::dict/string[2][text() = "20A5374g"]/../../array/dict/string[contains(., "pkg")]/text()' file.xml)
[[ $url ]] && wget "$url"
```